# Create a Background Service (Android, WP8) using Visual Studio - Cordova

Tags: windows-phone-8, cordova-plugins, visual-studio-cordova

I have created a Multi Device Hybrid App, it's working amazing. 
I want to create a background service for the app, which runs even if the app is closed. After reading some posts, I found out Cordova doesn't support this natively. 
Only addin I found was this one: https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode
It does the trick 50%, it works, as long as the app isn't force closed. That's not suitable.

Other posts I found was that I have to write a native service. But all posts are focusing on Phonegap / using Eclipse for the Android part. How do I write Java in the Visual Studio solution?

Comment: Anyone?? This must not be so hard, right?

Comment: Thanks for revealing that cordova-plugin-background-mode only works until the app is killed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to create a plugin in Visual Studio today.

That being said, the cordova library to create WP8 plugins can be found [here](https://github.com/apache/cordova-wp8/tree/master/wp8). This library can then be used to create a WP8 plugin as documented [here](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.5.0/guide_plugin-development_windows-phone_index.md.html)

Answer (score 0):

Alright, it is easier than I thought. I just have to write a plugin to call the native code. This is a create starting point: https://github.com/Red-Folder/bgs-core

I now can of course add a WP8 folder, add the required .cs files and it should work. However, how do I debug the plugin? I cannot find any information regarding developing/debugging plugins with Visual Studio. Also the documentation re debugging plugins for Cordova is not enough: http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.5.0/guide_plugin-development_windows-phone_index.md.html
It starts with "Add a file to the project", but what type of project? I cannot add a class file to a Cordova project.

Help is appreciated.